# how to disable Search Button- Android

Tags: android-widget

I am displaying a dialog while launching the app, and user has to click on that dialog to move on for next screens, so dialog should not close if user press back/search buttons of the device.

`dialog.setCancleble()` is working for back button but not for search button.

So, what should I implement to achieve this?

Comment: Android doesn't have a concept of dialogs. Instead you should properly save the state of your wizard and restore it on the next launch.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the Key Event in your Activity. Here is a little snippet which catches few Key Events,

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
                            // PhysicalMenuClicked=true;
                    }
                    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                    {
                        // CustomDialog.exitApp_Dialog(context);
                    }
                    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH  && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
                    {
                        return true; //true means that we are handling the event here.
                    }             
                    return true;
                }
```